# How to check whether session has timed out?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, visual-studio-2017, dynamics-crm

We've got 20 microservices that are all making use of a client library.

This library simply provides a way for the microservice to connect to its destination: CRM Dynamics.

Within each service we have a wrapper that calls this library:

```
public static class Client
{
    public static HttpClient Instance;
    static Client()
    {
        Instance = new TheCrmClient<AdfsAuthenticationHelper>(MyConfigSettings).HttpClient;

    }
}
```

Within each service we use the client like so:

```
        //Issue request
        var response = Client.Instance.SendAsync(request).Result;
```

After the ADFS session has timed out, we will get a 401 response.

**How do we force re-authentication when receiving a 401 response?**

**The authentication occurs in GetHttpsClient():**

```
public class TheCrmClient<T> where T : IAdfsAuthenticator
{
    private readonly RestCRMClientConfiguration _configuration;
    private IAdfsAuthenticator _authenticator;
    private HttpClient _https;

    public TheCrmClient(RestCRMClientConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public HttpClient HttpClient => GetClientHttps();

    private void InitializeAuthenticator(HttpClient client)
    {
        _authenticator = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), client) as IAdfsAuthenticator;
    }

    private HttpClient GetClientHttps()
    {
        var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            UseCookies = true,
            CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(),
            AllowAutoRedirect = false
        };

        _https = new HttpClient(clientHandler)
        {
            BaseAddress = _configuration.GetServiceUri(RestCRMClientConfiguration.UrlProtocolType.Https)
        };

        if (_authenticator == null)
            InitializeAuthenticator(_https);


        _authenticator.Authenticate(_configuration.GetNetworkCredential(),
            _configuration.GetAuthenticationTestEndpointUrl(RestCRMClientConfiguration.UrlProtocolType.Https));

        return _https;
    }
}
```

To clarify the lifecycle of the request is:

**Microservice.Controller --> Microservice.ClientWrapper --> TheCrmClientLibrary --> CrmDestination**

Comment: You can make a wrapper around httpclient, can be that TheCrmClient itself. Add SendAsync method there, call SendAsync of http client inside and check the response. If 401 - reauthenticate and try again. Otherwise - return response as is.

Comment: what do you think of doing it through a delegatinghandler?

Comment: That also seems fine to me, especially if you have a lot of code that relies on using HttpClient directly.

Comment: @Evk can you show an example of how to do this?

Comment: I cannot write code right now unfortunately. I think it goes like this: you inherit from DelegatingHandler, override SendAsync, make request (`base.SendAsync`), get response, check if 401 and if yes - reauthenticate then call `base.SendAsync` again and return response. Initialize client with `HttpClientFactory.Create(clientHandler, new YourDelegatingHandler)`

Comment: You could keep track of when the authentication happens and re-authenticate after a set period of time (I'd say, half the adfs timeout window). Easy to do and test.

Comment: @Alex thank you. how would i get the adfs timeout window in c#?